# WCF MSMQ order of handling requests

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I have a WCF msmq service with two method. MethodA and MethodB. A client calls First MethodA and then MethodB. Both are transactional.

My first question is, when this happens, are A and B processed after eachother? Then, when the server process is down are they also processed in the same order as they where called?

If this is not default behaviour, is there a way to enforce this?

Comment: I believe if your client calls the wcf **synchronously** then you can be sure messages are queued in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) and [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) properties of ServiceBehavior.

My guess is that you want to set `ConcurrencyMode.Single` and  `InstanceContextMode.Single` after which service could exist only in one instance and the other threads will wait while some thread is executing service method.

But be aware, that is the slowest one...